# Sling Resolution script calling order

Tags: aem, sling

I was looking over how sling will call the script on the basis of url. In the case of selector it seems work fine but if i use no selector, its confusing for me to understand:

I have a page `/content/AEMProject/English/test.html` which has resourceType `AEMProject/components/page/basepage` resouce basepage has 4 script files : `basepage.html.jsp , basepage.jsp , html.jsp, GET.jsp` . I red the Sling Best Match concept. So i have two strange cases.

1) My `basepage.html.jsp` is executing, as i consider it as best match. In case i delete this file `html.jsp` execute but i consider `basepage.jsp` as the 2nd best case.

2) In case i delete  `basepage.html.jsp , basepage.jsp , html.jsp` files my `GET.jsp` doesn't render.

I am considering here basepage as selector or IS is not.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `I am considering here basepage as selector or IS is not.`. Also when your GET.jsp is not executing what else is getting executed in its place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [sling docs](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-to-script-resolution.html) the rules for script path priorization is defined as follows:

> - The more request selectors are matched, the better.

(Note that a script with more than one selector doesn't get selected i.e, if you have a script x.y.jsp, where x and y are your selectors, it is ignored by sling. But it would still select the script `y.jsp`, present inside a folder `x` i.e., If the request is for test.x.y.html, then

```
-basepage
 |_x
   |_y.jsp (selected)
 |_x.y.jsp (ignored)
 |_x.jsp (selected in case x/y.jsp is not present. The script containing the first selector is chosen in such cases.)
```

> - A script including the request extension matches better than one without a request extension (for html only)
> - A script found earlier matches better than a script found later in the processing order. This means, that script closer to the original
>     resource type in the resource type hierarchy is considered earlier.

So now to answer your questions,

1. Your html.jsp would always take preference over your component.jsp, not the other way round.
2. Your GET.jsp should execute in the worst case scenario, i.e., when none of the other files are present, unless you have inherited this from some other component.

Comment: i read all the questions answered by you. Is there any other way to contact you means do you write any blogs or any cq related topics ?

Comment: Hi rakhi... in ur example u said if request is test.x.y.html then -basepage
 |_x
   |_y.jsp (selected) is executed... which i think wrong because even in developer guide example if request is /content/corporate/jobs/developer.print.a4.html

Comment: @user2142786 Even in the example given in the dev guide `print/a4.html.esp` takes preference over `print/a4/html.jsp` which in turn is preferred over `print/a4.jsp`. Since in my example I didnt use the extension and was explaining only selectors `x/y.jsp` is the one that is picked.

Comment: yes u r right actually i deleted that comment i don't know how its get published.. sorry for that :P :)