# How is the script resolved by Sling when we have two selectors?

Tags: aem, sling

Say I am having the following directory structure:

- listcomponent

  - listcomponent.jsp
  - renditions

    - overview.jsp
    - full.overview.jsp

The page myPage includes the list component.
When accessing a URL like http://localhost:4502/content/mysite/mypage.renditions.overview.html, the overview.jsp script is used. 
However, for http://localhost:4502/content/mysite/mypage.renditions.full.overview.html, the listcomponent.jsp script is used.

I'd like full.overview.jsp to be loaded in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case your overview.jsp should be full folder as below :

- listcomponent

  - listcomponent.jsp
  - renditions

    - overview.jsp
    - full

      - overview.jsp

Here is similar answer post. [Sling Resolution script calling order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213555/sling-resolution-script-calling-order)

Hope this will help.